# Facebook notification polling via RSS fails on second run, does anyone know why?

Tags: c#, xml, facebook, rss, polling

So I have a piece of code that works on the first call, and can tell me my most recent notification on Facebook via RSS. But, when I go to poll it the second time it freezes up right before\during the creation of the rssReader object.

```
private string getLatest()
    {
        var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(rssFeedURL);
        req.Method = "GET";
        req.UserAgent = "Fiddler";

        var rep = req.GetResponse();
        var rssReader = XmlTextReader.Create(rep.GetResponseStream());

        if(rssReader.ReadToFollowing("item"))
        {                
            rssReader.ReadToFollowing("title");
            return rssReader.ReadElementContentAsString();   
        }
        return latest;
    }
```

Could anyone tell me why this is? (This code is nearly identical to other's code that works)

It is called in this function:

```
public string alertFeed()
{
    string re = getLatest();
    if (re.Equals(latest))
            return null;
            latest = re;
            return "Facebook Notification, " + re;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Here's the fixed code, for anyone interested:

```
    private string getLatest()
    {

        var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(rssFeedURL);
        req.KeepAlive = false;
        req.Method = "GET";
        req.UserAgent = "Fiddler";
  --->  using (WebResponse rep = req.GetResponse())
        {
            var rssReader = XmlTextReader.Create(rep.GetResponseStream());

            if (rssReader.ReadToFollowing("item"))
            {
                rssReader.ReadToFollowing("title");
                return rssReader.ReadElementContentAsString();
            }
  --->  }
        return latest;
    }
```

The parts pointed to are what I had to add, as pointed out by Gratz, I could also have used rep.Close();.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe because you didn't close WebResponse "rep"

```
rep.Close();
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually ended up using the using keyword, but your solution worked as well.